# Node.JS Airtable - Await doesn't wait for promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get data from Airtable in my node.js app but I can't manage to get my results AFTER the resolution of my promise.

Here's my code:

```
async function getData(code) {
  return await airtableBase("Data")
    .select({
      filterByFormula: `{code} = "${code}"`,
    })
    .firstPage((err, records) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {};
      }

      console.log(records[0].fields);
      return records[0].fields;
    });
}
```

```
stuff.map(async (object) => {
      embedData = getEmbedData(object);

      data = await getData(embedData.code);

      console.log(data);
})
```

Here's what I get logged:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
{
  code: '1',
  fullname: 'Test 1',
  logo: '...'
}
{
  code: '2',
  fullname: 'Test 2',
  logo: '...'
}
{
  code: '3',
  fullname: 'Test 3',
  logo: '...'
}
```

Comment: you assume that `airtableBase(...).select(...).firstPage(...)` returns a Promise - it doesn't - rarely does a function that takes a node style callback ... `function(error, result)` rarely return a Promise

Comment: also .. `async function x() { return await y()}` is redundant ... and is better written `function x() { return y()}` if `y()` returns a promise (which it doesn't in your case as mentioned above)

Comment: Hmmm what do you mean? If I remove the "await" in the "data =" line, I get this logged:
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Nevermind I understand, it is returning a promise because it was a async function, right?

Comment: yes, `async` always returns a promise, but `.firstPage((err, records) => {})` does not return a Promise

Answer (score 6):

you assume that

```
airtableBase(...).select(...).firstPage((error, result) => {})
```

returns a Promise - it doesn't

rarely does a function that takes a node style callback ... i.e

```
function(error, result)
```

return a Promise

Change getData to return a Promise

```
function getData(code) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        airtableBase("Data")
        .select({
            filterByFormula: `{code} = "${code}"`,
        })
        .firstPage((err, records) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject({});
            }
            console.log(records[0].fields);
            resolve(records[0].fields);
        });
    });
}
```

also, with

```
stuff.map(async (object) => {
      embedData = getEmbedData(object);

      data = await getData(embedData.code);

      console.log(data);
})
```

there's no guarantee the order will be correct, it probably will be in this case, but there's no guarantee

The above is better written

```
Promise.all(stuff.map((object) => {
    embedData = getEmbedData(object);
    return getData(embedData.code);
}))
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(item => console.log(item));
})
```

or if that code is in a `async` function

```
const results = await Promise.all(stuff.map((object) => {
    embedData = getEmbedData(object);
    return getData(embedData.code);
}))
results.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Note: absolutely no rejection testing done since your code doesn't, but really, you should try/catch (if using async/await) or .catch if using .then

---

> Please note that `.firstPage` **may** actually return a Promise if no callback function is given, so your code may be simpler

```
function getData(code) {
    return airtableBase("Data")
    .select({
        filterByFormula: `{code} = "${code}"`,
    })
    .firstPage()
    .promise() /* this could be needed, again, depending on the library */
    .then(records => {
        return records[0].fields;
    });
}
```

However, as you have not indicated anything about the db library you are using, I can't be sure the above will work

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations, I now understand!

Comment: @RoiGoujat - please note, `.firstPage` **may** in fact return a Promise if you call it without a callback argument - but since you have not mentioned which db library you are using, I've assumed that it simply does not - I've just added code in case `.firstPage()` (i.e. without the callback) returns a promise

Comment: @RoiGoujat just as a heads up: in the `if (err)` block, there was no `return` statement before so if you've copied the above example, be sure to include it. Otherwise, if an error occurred, you'd also get a `cannot read property 0 of undefined` due to the `console.log` & `resolve()` outside the `if`. Also, your original code 'fails silently' by returning `{}` when an error occurs, you can mimic that in this version by doing `resolve({});` rather than `reject({});` or `reject(err);`.

Comment: @RickN - yeah, I'm sorry about that, I usually use an else block or `return reject()` - just "lazy" today :p